# Advert by categories inside the posts on function.php

Tags: wordpress, function, banner

I tryiend to add a banner inside the posts by categories. I got the follow code which show a banner after 1000 words. But, for example I want to show a banner if is a category 3 and a different banner is is a category 1. Can somebody tell me what exactly I need to add, please?

Regards.

Here is the code.

```
function inject_ad_text_after_n_chars($content) {
// only do this if post is longer than 1000 characters
$enable_length = 1000;
// insert after the first </p> after 160 characters
$after_character = 160;
if (is_single() && strlen($content) > $enable_length) {
$before_content = substr($content, 0, $after_character);
$after_content = substr($content, $after_character);
$after_content = explode('</p>', $after_content);
$text = '


    <center><a href="http://www.misite.net/descargar.php?go=1"       target="_blank">       <img src="http://www.misite.net/reproductor.jpg" alt="http://www.misite.net/reproductor.jpg" /></a></center>&nbsp

';
array_splice($after_content, 1, 0, $text);
$after_content = implode('</p>', $after_content);
return $before_content . $after_content;
}
else {
return $content;
}
}
```

I try with this but the show me a string error:

```
function inject_ad_text_after_n_chars($content) {
// only do this if post is longer than 1000 characters
$enable_length = 1000;
// insert after the first </p> after 160 characters
$after_character = 160;
if (is_single() && strlen($content) > $enable_length) {
$before_content = substr($content, 0, $after_character);
$after_content = substr($content, $after_character);
$after_content = explode('</p>', $after_content);
$text = '

if ( in_category( 1,3 ) ) {
$text = '<a href="http://www.misite.com/enlace"       target="_blank"><img     src="http://www.misite.com/banner1.jpg" alt="http://www.misite.com/banner1.jpg" /></a>';
} elseif ( in_category( 38158 ) ) {
$text = '<a href="http://www.misite.com/enlace"       target="_blank"><img  src="http://www.misite.com/banner2.jpg" alt="http://www.misite.com/banner2.jpg" /></a>';
} else {
$text = '<a href="http://www.misite.com/enlace"       target="_blank"><img src="http://www.misite.com/banner3.jpg" alt="http://www.misite.com/banner3.jpg" /></a>';
}


';
array_splice($after_content, 1, 0, $text);
$after_content = implode('</p>', $after_content);
return $before_content . $after_content;
}
else {
return $content;
}
}
```

Hello again!. Is working fine. So thanks guys! Here is the working code:

```
function inject_ad_text_after_n_chars($content) { 
// only do this if post is longer than 1000 characters 
$enable_length = 1000; 
// insert after the first </p> after 160 characters 
$after_character = 160; 
if (is_single() && strlen($content) > $enable_length) { 
$before_content = substr($content, 0, $after_character); 
$after_content = substr($content, $after_character); 
$after_content = explode('</p>', $after_content); 
if ( in_category( 1 ) ) { 
$text = '<center><a href="http://www.misite.com/enlace"       target="_blank"><img     src="http://www.misite.com/banner1.jpg" alt="http://www.misite.com/banner1.jpg" /></a></center>'; 
} elseif ( in_category( 3 ) ) { 
$text = '<center><a href="http://www.misite.com/enlace"       target="_blank"><img src="http://www.misite.com/banner2.jpg" alt="http://www.misite.com/banner2.jpg" /></a></center>';     
} elseif ( in_category( 4 ) ) { 
$text = '<center><a href="http://www.misite.com/enlace"       target="_blank"><img src="http://www.misite.com/banner3.jpg" alt="http://www.misite.com/banner3.jpg" /></a></center>'; 
} else { 
$text = '<center><a href="http://www.misite.com/enlace"       target="_blank"><img src="http://www.misite.com/bydefault.jpg" alt="http://www.misite.com/bydefault.jpg" /></a></center>'; 
} 
array_splice($after_content, 1, 0, $text); 
$after_content = implode('</p>', $after_content); 
return $before_content . $after_content; 
} 
else { 
return $content; 
} 
} 
add_filter('the_content', 'inject_ad_text_after_n_chars');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`in_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) conditional tag, example:

```
if ( in_category( 1 ) ) {
    $text = '<img src="http://example.com/banner-1.png">';
} elseif ( in_category( 3 ) ) {
    $text = '<img src="http://example.com/banner-3.png">';
} else {
    $text = '<img src="http://example.com/banner-default.png">';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help guys. I try with this but the show me a error. I will show in the firts post what I try. Regards